# How to replace and remove part of string in some places?

Tags: c#

This is the string i want to modify:

```
https://thistoreplacewithsomethingelse.test.com/thistoreplacewithsomethingelse/gg.mp4/vtt.mp4-3.jpg
```

i want to replace: `thistoreplacewithsomethingelse` with the string `mytest` and the second place with `thisistest` and in the end to remove the part: `/vtt.mp4-3.jpg`

so in the end it will looks like :

```
https://mytest.test.com/thisistest/gg.mp4
```

What i tried :

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\Videos");
for(int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
{
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(files[i]);
    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        var src = Regex.Match(line, "<img.+?src=[\"'](.+?)[\"'].*?>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Groups[1].Value;
        if(src != "" && src.Contains("mp4"))
        {
            //https://thumbs.mysite.com/thumbs/v/i/d/e/o/video14275.mp4/video14275mp4-3.jpg
            src.Replace("thumbs", "media");
            videosLinks.Add(src);
        }
    }
}
```

i tried to replace thumbs with media but there are two places with thumbs the second one i want to replace with videos.

and in the end to remove the last part: `/video14275mp4-3.jpg`

Comment: Please show your attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`Uri`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri?view=net-6.0) and the [`UriBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uribuilder?view=net-6.0) classes:

```
var uri = new Uri("https://thistoreplacewithsomethingelse.test.com/thistoreplacewithsomethingelse/gg.mp4/vtt.mp4-3.jpg");

string[] hostParts = uri.Host.Split('.');
hostParts[0] = "mytest";
string newHost = string.Join(".", hostParts);

UriBuilder uriBuilder = new UriBuilder();
uriBuilder.Scheme = "https";
uriBuilder.Host = newHost;
Uri fullUri = new Uri(uriBuilder.Uri, "thisistest/gg.mp4");

Console.Write(fullUri.ToString()); // https://mytest.test.com/thisistest/gg.mp4
```